# how to persist shared service data among component upon on reload

Tags: angular

I've written a service commonService that is used to share data between two components namely componentA (this sets the data) and componentB (this gets the data), but upon refreshing the componentB the data gets lost. Is there a way that I could persist the data upon reload.

```
@Injectable()
export class commonService { 
 private dataArray = [];

 setData (data: any) {
  this.dataArray = data;
} 

getData () {
 return this.dataArray
 }
}


 import {commonService} from './commonService';

export class componentA implements OnInit {

private dataArray = [1,2,3,4] 

constructor(private service: commonService) {
}
ngOnInit() {

 service.setData (dataArray);
}

}
    import {commonService} from './commonService';

    export class componentB implements OnInit {

    private dataArray = []; 

    constructor(private service: commonService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {

     dataArray = service.getData();
    } 
}
```

Comment: How come? Maybe you are using 2 instances of the same service (providers declaration does matter)

Comment: im not sure what your problem is exactly. Maybe it's solved if you just set a public variable dataArray on the service and write and listen to that one instead retrieving it once via an function of the service in the ngOnInit

Comment: Since there are couple of answers regarding reload of application - what refreash are you reffering to? Eg recreation of component, or reload of application eg. by hitting f5 to refrashe the page?

Comment: I'm doing F5 to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh page, share data will be lost.

You need use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to store share data in this case.

Comment: Either OP does not mean page reload (f5) or he needs to rephrase that.

Answer (score 0):

Your service need save data in LocalStorage or IndexedDB.

You can use such angular wrappers:
[ngx-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-localstorage) or
[ngx-indexed-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db)

Comment: Either OP does not mean page reload (f5) or he needs to rephrase that.